# Downloading is slower than should be, why? is there a solution?

Tags: linux, firefox, internet, download, mega

So, I recently downloaded Pop!_os, when downloading files from the internet I have felt some delay but no problem at all. When downloading via git, store, apt-get and pip the download speed was normal, but recently I tried to download some files via firefox and the download speed won't surpass 33 kbps, so I tried a mirror, same problem, so I did via terminal wget https://website.com/file and the same problem occured. Everything takes ages to download, until a friend of mine reuploaded the file via MEGA and the download speed reached about 700 kbps, something that had never happened before in Windows.

According to speedtest.net, my internet is of 10.64 mbps. Firefox version is: 68.0b11 (64-bits) [Nightly]

A developed version of my question would be:

Does wget uses firefox's download user agent? If so, is the problem with firefox itself? Is it possible to fix it, maybe through terminal? Or is it something with Pop!_os and some configuration file?

Comment: Are you on wireless? Try plugging in direct.

Comment: I tried, same problem...

Comment: qget does not use firefoxes download agent

Comment: Could be a proxy that is used by Firefox and not by others (o a TOR setup). You can go to some external site like showmyip.com and see if the IP it shows is the one you think you have.

Comment: @qget thanks for your answer, do you know which it uses by default?

Comment: @xenoid just did this, both IPs match

Answer (score -1):

try using IDM internet download manager !

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Can you expand your answer a bit? Just mentioning a product doesn't really explain how to accomplish the solution, and doesn't provide value beyond a random Google hit. Good guidance on recommending software here: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers.  Thanks.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for answering, it might help someone, I was very annoyed by the slowness so I uninstalled Pop!_OS, so I can't verify your answer. Did the same problem occured for you?